# Django not collecting static files

Tags: python, django, web

Im trying to collect static files on django production hosting
website: jumentosemuaresonline.com.br

My configuration:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".jumentosemuaresonline.com.br"]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/static/')
```

When i print static root on setting, returns the exact path of the ftp

```
/home/jumentosemuaresonline/apps_wsgi/website/static/
```

when i execute `python manage.py collectstatic -v 0`
It also return the exact path of the ftp

```
/home/jumentosemuaresonline/apps_wsgi/website/static/
```

But when i execute `python mange.py collectstatic` it dont fill the static folder with the static files, only returns

0 static files copied, 109 unmodified.

Anyone have idea what am i missing?

**I figured out what was happening:**
The collect static command was working fine but I was using Nginx in front of the application as a reverse proxy, Nginx has to serve the static path not django.

```
upstream django_app {
    server djangohost:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /my/static_path/;
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems command is running fine, are you sure you looking at correct path? if there is no modification then it won't copy the file.

Comment: the folder /home/jumentosemuaresonline/apps_wsgi/website/static/ is empty

Comment: What is the value of STATICFILES_DIRS? Also it seems like STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL points to same location.

Comment: I´m not using STATICFILES_DIRS, all the static files are under my aplication static files folder, and is working on my machine on debug true mode.

Comment: I was missing the nginx configurations to serve static files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says 109 unmodified. The files are already there.
Try `ls /home/jumentosemuaresonline/apps_wsgi/website/static/`
That should show you all the files there.

Just in case. Try this too.

`rm -rf /home/jumentosemuaresonline/apps_wsgi/website/static/
mkdir /home/jumentosemuaresonline/apps_wsgi/website/static/
python manage.py collectstatic`

This should show you 109 copied and 0 modified.

Comment: I was missing Nginx config